# Trying to return biggest count on group sorted model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I have a many-to-many :through relationship going.
Users -> Memberships <- Groups

User model has a :country column.

Now I want to find out **how many people of the same country** are in a specific group and **return only the country with the biggest amount** of users.

I have this atm in by Group model;

```
def country
 Country.find(users.group(:country_id).count.keys.first)
end
```

Which does not work, I saw it returns an OrderedHash, where I'm now taking the first key of, which is pointless. Just showing you were I'm lost I guess.

I want to be able to do @group.country and get the biggest country in that group.

Any help on how I would go about this?

Comment: Where did Country come from?  do you mean users belongs_to country ?

Comment: Yea sorry, I also have a model Country where I have just all the countries of the world in. It has_many Users. And Users belongs_to country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a lot easier if you used the `:counter_cache` feature of ActiveRecord because the numbers would be expressed in a column you could index and sort on. The alternative is to write some custom SQL to get the proper result.

The alternative is to wrangle around with a group like you have:

```
Country.find(users.group(:country_id).count.first.first)
```